# issue with installing rtl8852au driver on mobile robot with rpi4

Tags: driver

Good morning y'all!

Happy Easter to you kind souls!

I'm stuck trying to get my new TP-Link AX1800 - Archer TX20U Plus working on my mobile Robot I'm working on.
The Archer TX20U Plus is based on the RTL8852AU chipset and I'm struggling getting the driver to work on Ubuntu 22.04.
Installation details:

a) raspberry pi 4b

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
    processor       : 0
    BogoMIPS        : 108.00
    Features        : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
    CPU implementer : 0x41
    CPU architecture: 8
    CPU variant     : 0x0
    CPU part        : 0xd08
    CPU revision    : 3

    processor       : 1
    BogoMIPS        : 108.00
    Features        : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
    CPU implementer : 0x41
    CPU architecture: 8
    CPU variant     : 0x0
    CPU part        : 0xd08
    CPU revision    : 3

    processor       : 2
    BogoMIPS        : 108.00
    Features        : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
    CPU implementer : 0x41
    CPU architecture: 8
    CPU variant     : 0x0
    CPU part        : 0xd08
    CPU revision    : 3

    processor       : 3
    BogoMIPS        : 108.00
    Features        : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
    CPU implementer : 0x41
    CPU architecture: 8
    CPU variant     : 0x0
    CPU part        : 0xd08
    CPU revision    : 3

    Hardware        : BCM2835
    Revision        : b03111
    Serial          : 10000000:-)xxx0
    Model           : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
```

b)

```
lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Release:        22.04
    Codename:       jammy
```

c)

```
uname -i
    aarch64
```

d)

```
uname -a
    Linux autobotv2 5.15.0-1026-raspi #28-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 10 14:28:52 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I have found this Github repo and have followed the instructions exactly.

```
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8852au
```

Here are the steps I have performed:

1. plugged in the device to USB
2. lsusb shows: Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:013f TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
3. updated and amde sure all requirements are met / latest

```
sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
```

4. created a new directory in my home folder and cloned the git into it:

```
mkdir src
    cd src
    git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8852au.git
```

5. made sure to update the udev rules matching my device listed in lsusb output

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
    and added the below two lines to the bottom
        # tp-link AX1800 - Archer TX20U Plus (rtl8852au chipset)
        ATTR{idVendor}=="2357", ATTR{idProduct}=="013f", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

-> by the way /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules contains the same two lines in the bottom. Must be the same file or a symlink!?
6. Then continued with the build process and install

```
 cd rtl8852au
    make
    sudo make install
```

7. I did not get any error output and the install process was flawless. That was yesterday evening. I do not have the terminal trace though.
8. reboot
9. ifconfig shows only loopback and the built-in wifi as wlan0, but not the plugged tp-link :-/

```
 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 102  bytes 8824 (8.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 102  bytes 8824 (8.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.68.201  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.68.255
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe2a:7e96  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:2a:7e:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 495  bytes 66254 (66.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 41  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 609  bytes 142954 (142.9 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

10. lsusb still shows the device listed, same as under step 2. My understand is, that the udev rules should unload it and not list it with lsusb?

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:013f TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
```

Same output as before I started installing any drivers. So this has never changed

Here is the output of dkms status

```
8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025: added
rtl8821au/5.12.5.2, 5.15.0-1026-raspi, aarch64: installed
rtl8852au/1.15.0.1: added
```

nmcli dev wifi

```
nmcli dev wifi
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
    68:FF:7B:21:??:E3  Home                   Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
    6E:FF:7B:21:??:E3  --                  Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2
    68:FF:7B:21:??:F3  Home                Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  92      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
    6E:FF:7B:21:??:F3  --                  Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  90      ▂▄▆█  WPA2
    82:D9:82:30:??:9C  2degrees            Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA2 WPA3
    82:D9:82:30:??:98  2degrees            Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA2 WPA3
    74:??:28:1F:A0:24  AONET-1             Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  21      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
    68:FF:7B:21:??:21  Home                Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
    68:FF:7B:21:??:A0  Home                Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
    6E:FF:7B:21:??:A0  --                  Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2
    6E:FF:7B:21:??:21  --                  Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA2
    88:DC:96:56:94:FE  --                  Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  --
    82:D9:82:30:??:94  2degrees            Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA2 WPA3
    21:80:88:FC:F1:D1  --                  Infra  13    270 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA2
    2E:80:88:FC:F1:D1  Lan                 Infra  13    270 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA2
    18:FD:74:36:B1:35  AONET-3             Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
    0A:18:A0:2D:??:85  Mo                  Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
    88:DC:96:56:95:55  --                  Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  --
```

modinfo 8852au

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-1026-raspi/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw89/8852au.ko
version:        v1.15.0.1-0-g487ee886.20210714
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     CA3688458F929C1F84A1DFB
alias:          usb:v2357p0141d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v2357p013Fd*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v2001p3321d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0411p0312d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1A62d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1997d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp885Cd*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp885Ad*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8832d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
depends:        cfg80211
name:           8852au
vermagic:       5.15.0-1026-raspi SMP preempt mod_unload modversions aarch64
parm:           rtw_wireless_mode:int
parm:           rtw_band_type:int
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_lps_level:The default LPS level (int)
parm:           rtw_lps_chk_by_tp:int
parm:           rtw_max_bss_cnt:int
parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
parm:           rtw_dynamic_agg_enable:int
parm:           rtw_tx_bw_mode:The max tx bw for 2.4G and 5G. format is the same as rtw_bw_mode (uint)
parm:           rtw_max_amsdu_len:uint
parm:           rtw_rx_ampdu_sz_limit_1ss:RX AMPDU size limit for 1SS link of each BW, 0xFF: no limitation (array of uint)
parm:           rtw_rx_ampdu_sz_limit_2ss:RX AMPDU size limit for 2SS link of each BW, 0xFF: no limitation (array of uint)
parm:           rtw_rx_ampdu_sz_limit_3ss:RX AMPDU size limit for 3SS link of each BW, 0xFF: no limitation (array of uint)
parm:           rtw_rx_ampdu_sz_limit_4ss:RX AMPDU size limit for 4SS link of each BW, 0xFF: no limitation (array of uint)
parm:           rtw_vht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vht_24g_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vht_rx_mcs_map:VHT RX MCS map (uint)
parm:           rtw_he_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rf_path:int
parm:           rtw_tx_nss:int
parm:           rtw_rx_nss:int
parm:           rtw_country_code:The default country code (in alpha2) (charp)
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:The default chplan ID when rtw_alpha2 is not specified or valid (int)
parm:           rtw_excl_chs:exclusive channel array (array of uint)
parm:           rtw_pci_dynamic_aspm_linkctrl:int
parm:           rtw_qos_opt_enable:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_vo_edca:uint
parm:           rtw_ap_src_b2u_flags:int
parm:           rtw_ap_fwd_b2u_flags:int
parm:           rtw_wowlan_sta_mix_mode:int
parm:           rtw_pwrtrim_enable:int
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_hw_rts_en:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_rx_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_tx_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_quick_addba_req:int
parm:           rtw_beamform_cap:int
parm:           rtw_sw_proto_bf_cap_phy0:int
parm:           rtw_sw_proto_bf_cap_phy1:int
parm:           rtw_dyn_txbf:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_full_ch_in_p2p_handshake:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_drv_ant_band_switch:int
parm:           rtw_single_ant_path:int
parm:           rtw_switch_usb_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_check_hw_status:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_hiq_filter:0:allow all, 1:allow special, 2:deny all (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_en:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_mode:0:normal, 1:carrier sense (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_th_l2h_ini:th_l2h_ini for Adaptivity (int)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_th_edcca_hl_diff:th_edcca_hl_diff for Adaptivity (int)
parm:           rtw_dfs_region_domain:0:UNKNOWN, 1:FCC, 2:MKK, 3:ETSI (uint)
parm:           rtw_amsdu_mode:0:non-spp, 1:spp, 2:all drop (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_2g:BIT3:2G ext-PA, BIT4:2G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_5g:BIT6:5G ext-PA, BIT7:5G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_rfe_type:default init value:64 (uint)
parm:           rtw_dbcc_en:0:Disable, 1:Enable DBCC (int)
parm:           rtw_powertracking_type:default init value:64 (uint)
parm:           rtw_GLNA_type:default init value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_2G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_5G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_OffEfuseMask:default open Efuse Mask value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_FileMaskEfuse:default drv Mask Efuse value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_rxgain_offset_2g:default RF Gain 2G Offset value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_rxgain_offset_5gl:default RF Gain 5GL Offset value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_rxgain_offset_5gh:uint
parm:           rtw_rxgain_offset_5gm:default RF Gain 5GM Offset value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_pll_ref_clk_sel:force pll_ref_clk_sel, 0xF:use autoload value (uint)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_target_tx_pwr_2g_a:2.4G target tx power (unit:dBm) of RF path A for each rate section, should match the real calibrate power, -1: undefined (array of int)
parm:           rtw_target_tx_pwr_2g_b:2.4G target tx power (unit:dBm) of RF path B for each rate section, should match the real calibrate power, -1: undefined (array of int)
parm:           rtw_target_tx_pwr_2g_c:2.4G target tx power (unit:dBm) of RF path C for each rate section, should match the real calibrate power, -1: undefined (array of int)
parm:           rtw_target_tx_pwr_2g_d:2.4G target tx power (unit:dBm) of RF path D for each rate section, should match the real calibrate power, -1: undefined (array of int)
parm:           rtw_target_tx_pwr_5g_a:5G target tx power (unit:dBm) of RF path A for each rate section, should match the real calibrate power, -1: undefined (array of int)
parm:           rtw_target_tx_pwr_5g_b:5G target tx power (unit:dBm) of RF path B for each rate section, should match the real calibrate power, -1: undefined (array of int)
parm:           rtw_target_tx_pwr_5g_c:5G target tx power (unit:dBm) of RF path C for each rate section, should match the real calibrate power, -1: undefined (array of int)
parm:           rtw_target_tx_pwr_5g_d:5G target tx power (unit:dBm) of RF path D for each rate section, should match the real calibrate power, -1: undefined (array of int)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)
parm:           rtw_phydm_ability:uint
parm:           rtw_halrf_ability:uint
parm:           rtw_en_napi:int
parm:           rtw_en_gro:int
parm:           rtw_iqk_fw_offload:int
parm:           rtw_ch_switch_offload:int
parm:           rtw_en_dyn_rrsr:int
parm:           rtw_rrsr_value:int
parm:           rtw_scan_interval_thr:Threshold used to judge if scan request comes from scan UI, unit is ms. (uint)
parm:           rtw_roch_min_home_dur:uint
parm:           rtw_roch_max_away_dur:uint
parm:           rtw_roch_extend_dur:uint
```

Not sure if that means the driver is properly installed.
Is there a command to list all atatched network interfaces other than ifconfig? Something that goes a bit more in depth? Because afaik ifconfig only shows active interfaces that are "up". I also tried "sudo ifup wlan1" but as you might guess that also didn't work..

lsmod | grep 8852

```
8852au              13656064  0
cfg80211              966656  2 8852au,brcmfmac
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing, or what else I can try? I bought this adapter specifically because google research before purchase showed compatibility and easy to use in non-windows environments.
The issue with raspberry pi's built-in wifi is, that it performs poorly, since it is tucked away inside the Robot, that's why I need a cable extended USB wifi adapter.

Please help!